# INNER JOIN , I don't know why im getting Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

is there anything wrong with this code? i seem to have 3 tables pelajar, bacaan, gurukelas and all the values are correct and i double checked them. I just want to have justification whether I code it correctly :)

```
$dataD = mysqli_query($hubung,"
    SELECT COUNT(pelajar.idpelajar) as bilang,
    pelajar.idpelajar,
    pelajar.nama,
    pelajar.jantina,
    gurukelas.kelas FROM pelajar
    INNER JOIN bacaan ON bacaan.idpelajar
    INNER JOIN gurukelas ON gurukelas.idguru
    GROUP BY bacaan.idpelajar
    ORDER BY bilang DESC
");
```

Comment: The join's in the `FROM` clause are incomplete. `ON bacaan.idpelagar = pelajar.idpelajar`, and the need the same for the `gurukelas` JOIN too.

Comment: Take a look at manual of `mysqli_query` https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php. It says "Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE."

Since your warning is bool given and your query is a select, then it must be returning FALSE. Do `var_dump($dataD)` to confirm. Also check the logs for errors.

Morever, what @PaulT. said is also valid. You miss JOIN condition, although that won't cause `mysqli_query` to return FALSE.